# passing data between view controllers programmatically Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have two viewcontroller classes. MainViewController has a UITextField and SecondViewController has a UILabel. I want to print the text from the UITextField in the UILabe. Please tell me the best way to do this programmatically. Below is my code:

```
// AppDelegate.swift

import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

  var window: UIWindow?


  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
```

window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

```
window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

window?.rootViewController = MainViewController()

window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow

application.statusBarStyle = .lightContent


return true
  }

 }
```

// MainViewController Class

```
import UIKit

class MainViewController: UIViewController {


  let label = UILabel()

  let textField = UITextField()



  override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()


    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
    setupLabel()
    setupTextField()
    setupButton()
  }

  func setupLabel() {

    label.frame = CGRect(x: 40, y: 80, width: 300, height: 60)
    label.text = "welcome to my world"
    label.textColor = UIColor.yellow
    label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 25)
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.layer.borderWidth = 2
    label.layer.borderColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
    label.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    view.addSubview(label)
  }

  func setupTextField() {

    textField.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 200, width: self.view.frame.size.width - 20, height: 60)
    textField.placeholder = "text here"
    textField.textAlignment = .center
    textField.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 25)
    textField.layer.borderWidth = 2
    textField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
    textField.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    view.addSubview(textField)
  }

  func setupButton() {

    let button = UIButton()
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 300, width: self.view.frame.size.width - 100, height: 60)
    button.setTitle("Enter", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.yellow, for: .normal)
    button.layer.borderWidth = 2
    button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTarget), for: .touchUpInside)
    view.addSubview(button)
  }

  func buttonTarget() {

    // i missed here maybe
    }

}
```

// SecondViewController class

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {


    let secondLabel = UILabel()

  override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    setupLabelSecond()
  }


  func setupLabelSecond() {

    secondLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 40, y: 80, width: 300, height: 60)
    secondLabel.text = "this is Second Page"
    secondLabel.textColor = UIColor.yellow
    secondLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 25)
    secondLabel.textAlignment = .center
    secondLabel.layer.borderWidth = 2
    secondLabel.layer.borderColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
    secondLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    view.addSubview(secondLabel)
  }



}
```

Comment: @vadian could you answer him please or some hints

Comment: @vadian  i am trying to do it without storyboard.

Comment: There are also suggestions without storyboard.

Comment: with out storyboard, how do you created the Second VC, in progrmatically or Xib or else

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik can check codes again please because edited newly

Comment: @AzmalTech - I added the answer for progrmatically also

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you need to follow some steps

**step1**

initially embed with your initial VC to navigation controller , for e.g

> Now select the first controller in Storyboard and click on **Editor > Embed in... > Navigation Controller.**

[image]

**step2**

Now you have to link the second Controller in Storyboard with your new SecondViewController.swift file.

> Select the yellow circle at the top of the controller, click on the Identify inspector panel icon on the right side of the XCode window, and type the name of your new .swift file in the Class and StoryboardID fields

for e.g

[image]

**step3**

**Passing a String**

> Now select the other controller in Storyboard and add this variable right below the SecondViewController class declaration:

```
 class SecondViewController: UIViewController {


let secondLabel = UILabel()

  var stringPassed = ""
```

> Make the app assign the value of this variable to secondLabel with the following line of code in the **viewDidLoad()** method

**step4**

on your first VC , inside the button

```
func buttonTarget() {

    let myVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondVC") as! SecondViewController
    myVC.stringPassed = label.text!

    navigationController?.pushViewController(myVC, animated: true)

}
```

finally you get the out put as

```
 func setupLabelSecond() {
    
    secondLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 40, y: 80, width: 300, height: 60)

    if let outputText =  stringPassed
    {
    secondLabel.text = outputText
    }else
     {
      secondLabel.text = "this is Second Page"
     }
    secondLabel.textColor = UIColor.yellow
    secondLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 25)
    secondLabel.textAlignment = .center
    secondLabel.layer.borderWidth = 2
    secondLabel.layer.borderColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
    secondLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    view.addSubview(secondLabel)
  }
```

for sample you can get the tutorial [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-passing-data-between-controllers-in-swift--cms-27151)

**update for XIB**

```
   func buttonTarget() {

    var vcPass = SecondViewController(nibName: "SecondViewController", bundle: nil)
     vcPass.stringPassed = label.text!
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vcPass, animated: true)


}
```

**update for without XIB and Storboard**

**change your appdelegate**

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
   
    let navigation = UINavigationController(rootViewController: MainViewController())
    self.window?.rootViewController = navigation
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
 }
```

**on your MainViewController**

```
 func buttonTarget() {

     var vcPass = SecondViewController()
     vcPass.stringPassed = label.text!
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vcPass, animated: true)

 }
```

**Passing a String**

> Now select the other controller in Storyboard and add this variable right below the SecondViewController class declaration:

```
 class SecondViewController: UIViewController {


let secondLabel = UILabel()

  var stringPassed = ""
```

> Make the app assign the value of this variable to secondLabel with the following line of code in the **viewDidLoad()** method

func setupLabelSecond() {

```
    secondLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 40, y: 80, width: 300, height: 60)

    if let outputText =  stringPassed
    {
    secondLabel.text = outputText
    }else
     {
      secondLabel.text = "this is Second Page"
     }
    secondLabel.textColor = UIColor.yellow
    secondLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 25)
    secondLabel.textAlignment = .center
    secondLabel.layer.borderWidth = 2
    secondLabel.layer.borderColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
    secondLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    view.addSubview(secondLabel)
  }
```

Comment: @NazmulHasan - r u using Xib or else

Comment: probably not! he give me simple by mail

Comment: @NazmulHasan - pardon, I ready to help,but  how do u created the secondviewcontroller frame

Comment: @NazmulHasan - I updated the answer for Xib also, if it is fine ok , else if u tell I will modify my answer

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik i edited code. can you check it again please? actually i like to do it with programmatically.

Comment: @NazmulHasan - I added the answer for progrmatically also

Comment: @NazmulHasan - I updated the answer with appdelegate also

Comment: @NazmulHasan - on your second VC, no need to change any line,

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik thanks for  your help.also  hope Azmaltech by the answer

Comment: @NazmulHasan - pardon, if u need help related to this I surely help,

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik thanks i accepted your answer and also thanks to Nazmul Hasan

Comment: @NazmulHasan - now I leave frm my place if you need the assitance related to this , i Surely help you on tomorrow mrng indian time 9.30 A.M

Answer (score 3):

I know 2 possible ways.

1) Embed your initial view controller in navigation controller.
 In your 2nd view create a var. eg

`var x = ""`

in your 1st view create a text field outlet and object of second view controller ,

```
@IBOutlet weak var enteredName: UITextField!

let secondVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondViewController") as! secondViewController
```

then, assign the entered text field through that object to variable x.

```
secondVC.x = enteredName.text!
```

in your second vc you can assign the value of x to your label.

```
mylabel.text = x
```

**____________________________________________________________________**

Second Method is using user Defaults.

take user input and set that as user default.

```
 let defaults = UserDefaults.standard   
defaults.set(self.enteredName.text!,forKey: "userName")
    defaults.synchronize()
```

and in your second view use

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard  
yourlabel.text = defaults.object(forKey: "userName")
```