# Passing double digit data between two ViewControllers

Tags: swift, xcode

In my current project I tried to pass data between two ViewControllers (ViewController1 and ViewController2). Specifically, I have a counter which I would like to remain counting when switched to the second ViewController.

The first ViewController contains a 'double INT' value *Counter*. I managed passing the data via below code.

**The code of ViewController1:**

```
class ViewController1: UIViewController {

    var counter = 00.00

    @objc func UpdateTimer() {
        counter = counter + 0.1
    }
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if let ViewController2 = segue.destination as? ViewController2 {
        ViewController2.counter = self.counter
    }
}
```

Comment: The error is quite explicit, you try assign the first value which is Double type to a variable of type String. Can you show the code line where you assign the value and how do you declare the variable in the second view controller ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [passing data between view controllers programmatically Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42608097/passing-data-between-view-controllers-programmatically-swift)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You have to add double type variable in second view controller:

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    var doubleValue: Double?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}
```

> And from the first view controller, you can send the value like this:

```
if let secondVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "doubleValue") as? SecondViewController {

            secondVC.doubleValue = 1.22
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondVC, animated: true)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you probably declare a double type value in your second viewController and you can pass value in the first viewController by this way (if you use segue)

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "segueIdentifier" {
        if let destViewController = segue.destination as? secondViewController {
            destViewController.doubleValue = self.doubleValue
        }
    }
}
```